# Signing (HMAC) cookie identifier

Tags: digital-signature, cookies, hmac, session-management

[Related to this other question about sharing the secret to sign the cookies](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/47704/26231), my question is more trivial: how really secure is to *sign* a simple cookie identifier?

In example, [`expressjs#session` library requires a secret](https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret), but also says at the begining of the docs:

> Session data is *not* saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.

But I don't see any benefit to create an HMAC of an identifier, because this value will be anyway a *bearer token* for server state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that an HMAC provides little added security if the session ID is something that is hard to guess. For example, a long secure PRNG. But if the session ID is simple to guess then there is the risk of [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

As the `expressjs` framework allows you to provide a [session ID creation function](https://github.com/expressjs/session#genid) that returns IDs with unknown security properties, an HMAC seems like a good strategy.

The default uses the `uid2` library which looks like (I'm not a NodeJS user so I'm not certain) a secure PRNG (see [source code](https://github.com/coreh/uid2/blob/master/index.js)). An HMAC seems of less value in this case.

Comment: Just to give an example, suppose the server's token generator is just a counter. If you have token `17`, you can be pretty sure `16` and `18` are valid tokens, too. If an attacker needs a MAC of that token, though, then knowing that `16` is a valid token doesn't help (because the token is really `16` *and* `HMAC(16, secret_key)`).

Comment: Then, the only reason, is the "guessing" possibility, and if the session ID is _hard_ enough, signing is _useless_. I'm right?

Comment: Yes @datakey, if the session is crypto secure the HMAC seems unnecessary.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `uid2`, the built-in `crypto` module can be used with e.g. `crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("base64")` to generate crypto random data